# android studio / flutter icons suggestions do not show

Tags: flutter, android-studio

when I type Icons.??? the suggestions don't show up the spinner keeps spinning but never finishes but regular suggestion for regular code show up with no problems. It was working before but I don't know why it stopped working

- when I scroll through icons. it loads out very slowly and the ones that are loaded show up in the suggestions

I have tried invalidate caches/restart but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Do **Flutter Clean** (Tools>Flutter>Flutter Clean) then **Flutter Pub get**
and make sure that   cupertino_icons is installed in pubspec.yaml file

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: I tried. didn't work

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Try reinstalling the flutter plugin in android studio. This also happens if you have downgraded and upgraded flutter one or more times